# Compile single .java file with two classes into two .class files

Tags: java, class, compiler-construction, intellij-idea, runtimeexception

I currently have a .java file set up like this:

```
package com.ds;

class c{...}

public class Main{...}
```

When I compile the file Main.java, it results in a single .class file being Main.class.

When I try to run the .class with `java com.ds.Main` it does not work! It says it cannot find or load the class.

When I try to run the .class with `java Main` it runs, but I get an error like so:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main (wrong name: com
/DatingService/Main)


at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

I've seen this before while trying to find a solution and none of the solutions I found  applied to me or just didn't work.

After doing a bit more research I am assuming that javac will not split the classes within a file by at least default? I know that many IDEs like Eclipse and IntelliJ split the classes into two separate .class files (I can confirm this). So is there any way for javac to do this? I'm using javac as my compiler for IntelliJ so there must be a way unless it's done before compiling.

If I remove the package, I can run java Main perfectly fine with only a single .class file compiled. So I'm a bit confused, and a little desperate. I am trying to completely avoid changing my code or splitting the classes into two separate .java files.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an urgent matter that will be of little interest to future visitors.

Comment: Is it typo or is it real that your package is `com.ds` while `Main` class is inside `com/DatingService`? Anyway I cant reproduce your error. If I have two classes (one public) in `MyPublicClass.java` file  I get two `class` files if compiled with `javac MyPublicClass.java`.

Comment: The real package name is com.DatingService, I simply shortened it for the example. They are both in the same package in the same .java file. They compile fine but I can't run it. Is there a special way to run something like this? java com.DatingService.Main doesn't work as I said above

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using classpath. And it doesn't look like you're searching all that hard for the second class file which likely has been created.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have no knowledge of how to use classpath, I've tried a few things I found around the internet and they compile but also do not run. I've found the second .class file now, it was buried under a bunch of files. I've set the output directory for compiling using -d now and I see it, however the problem still persists.

My folder structure is like so: `./Dating Service\src\com\DatingService`

With my the .java file being `Main.java` in the folder `.\DatingService`

Comment: Why not save yourself a mountain of pain and just use an IDE? Who runs javac from the commandline these days...

Comment: @BoristheSpider I am using an IDE, I use IntelliJ and everything works perfectly when debugging and building, even making a jar artifact works flawlessly. But the person reviewing this is using javac, why? Because that person knows no better (and I have no control over this). I even provided them with .class files and .jar files from the IDE but, that person likes to compile the code then run... I don't get it, but I literally have no authority for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are doing wrong so I will just show you how it can be done.

Lets say you have directories and files

```
[myProject]
  |
  +--[src]
  |    |
  |    +--[com]
  |        |
  |        +--[DatingService]
  |            |
  |            +-- Main.java
  |
  +--[classes]
```

and your Main.java file looks something like

```
package com.DatingService;

class c{
    private int i;
    public void setI(int i){
        this.i=i;
    }
    public int getI(){
        return this.i;
    }
}

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        c myCVariable = new c();

        myCVariable.setI(10);
        System.out.println(myCVariable.getI());
    }
}
```

In terminal you need to go to `myProject` directory and from it use

myProject>`javac -d classes src\com\DatingService\Main.java`

Thanks to `-d` (directory) parameter packages with all compiled classes should be placed in `classes` directory (note that `classes` directory must already exist). So `c.class` and `Main.class` will be placed in `myProject\classes\com\DatingService`.

Now to run `main` method from `Main` class you just need to provide information about directory that contains your packages (this is ClassPath) and also use `full.package.name.to.your.MainClass`. So you will have to add `-classpath classes` (or shorter `-cp classes`) parameter to your `java` command and run it like

myProject>`java -cp classes com.DatingService.Main`

(note: there is no `.java` suffix after `Main` class since JVM is running binaries stored in `.class` files, not code from `.java` files)

Comment: That did the trick! And thank you so much for the explanation! It makes a lot of sense now.

Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Specify where to place the generated class files using the -d option. 
Eg. If you want to compile it to the current directory where your prompt is, use

```
javac -d . Main.java
```

It will create the folder structure com/ds in you current directory and place the two class files in there.
Then run using

```
java com.ds.Main
```

Comment: I have no idea why, but that did the trick when using the `.` for the directory, however if I change that to anything else I still get exceptions and such. Also I cannot get this working in my file structure, only when I place the .java in the JDK bin folder

Comment: If you specify '-d something-else' to javac, you have to specify '-classpath something-else' to java.